# How to ssh into linux host in VMware Workstation 15

Tags: windows, networking, ubuntu, ssh, vmware-workstation

I am using [VMware Workstation 15](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/downloads/details?downloadGroup=WKST-1550-WIN&productId=799) inside Windows 10. I have created an Ubuntu instance under it. From another machine, I can `ssh` into it if I am connected into local network, but I am unable to connect into it using the public ip of the Windows machine.

- If I use Bridged network option, `ifconfig` in ubuntu host returns a local ip-address, which I can ssh into if I am in local network.
- One possible solution I was thinking to ssh into Windows-powershell and if I can, I can ssh into the VM.

**[Q]** How can I connect into Ubuntu instance that is running inside VMware Workstation using its public ip?

Accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52386841/how-to-do-port-forwarding-on-vmware-player-14-1-2-ubuntu-18-04-guest-windows-1) is for the older version of VMware Workstation.

---

I couldn't find proper guide for the VMware Workstation 15, all the ones I find are for its older versions, as such:

=> https://www.virten.net/2013/03/how-to-setup-port-forwarding-in-vmware-workstation-9/

=> https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Fusion/11/com.vmware.fusion.using.doc/GUID-D884CB72-28A5-4F03-9B82-783F523C256C.html

---

My original question is closed on stackoverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/q/64081856/2402577), hence I was advised to ask in here.

Comment: There isn’t anything about that answer that doesn’t apply to Workstation 15 or 16; I would agree with the SO answer.  This is based on my many years working with VMWARE products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need two port-forwarding rules.
[First rule](https://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/general-port-forwarding-guide/) from your home router to your windows 10 host.
Then [second rule](https://sites.google.com/a/smccme.edu/vmware-workstation-port-forward-to-vm-in-nat/) from windows 10 into Ubuntu guest VM.

You can get rid of the second rule by bridging your VM instead of NAT

Comment: Sorry for late response, in my modem's interface I have permission to create port mapping assigning `Public Port` and `LAN Port` ; or setting `Port Triggering` option. Not sure what should I set to public and LAN port

Comment: Follow Rule #1, then Rule #2. Rule #1 will forward from public port to LAN port. Rule #2 will forward from host to VM

Comment: First rule site does not open on my end, is there any alternative link for that?